# Command line tool for fetching and analyzing SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, heartbleed

Following the [heartbleed vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) in openSSL, all the SSH certificate on our servers were re-issued and re-installed.

Since it is likely that we've missed something on a server (for example, restarting Apache), we are checking the servers manually by clicking the key logo in Chrome:

[image]

This is slow and error prone. Is there a command line tool that can fetch the certificate ID/Serial number from a server?

**Update**

I ended up using a variation on [MichelZ's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/589696/10904):

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -status -verify 0 \
        -connect www.mydomain.com:443 2>&1 | \
        egrep "Verify return|subject=/serial"
```

- `echo` is necessary for `openssl` to exit (it waits for input otherwise).
- `-verify 0` verifies the certificate.
- `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard output
- `egrep` shows only the validation status and the serial number.

Comment: don't forget to use  `-servername` for `SNI` (server name indication) when you have multiple vhosts.

Comment: `-servername` not needed for `SNI` since version 1.1.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use OpenSSL to retrieve the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect some_server:server_port
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I've adapted your answer to my needs and it works perfectly. Thanks!